# WPF MVVM binding. Same view, different objects

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm

I'm building my first WPF application and am endeavoring to follow MVVM principles.

I have a situation where I'm using my viewModel to build an object up from my entities spread across 8 different database tables using LINQ, ready to populate a treeview.

This is working fine.

What I now need to do is change what object I bind to the *same* view. For example in simple cases the object may have a different order by, or more importantly I may filter on the source of the entity which will require a completely different query joining across additional tables but ultimately the resulting object will be the same structure for binding to my treeview.

Here's my main method:

```
public EntityViewModel()
    {
        using (var model = _app.OrmContext.CreateUnitOfWork())
        {
             // get unique entity names, we always need this in the filtering drop-down
            var names = (
                from tt 
                in model.EntityTypes
                    .OrderBy(o => o.Name)
                    select new EntityType
                    {
                        Name = tt.Name
                    }).Distinct().ToList();

            _entityNamesUnique.AddRange(names);

            var collection =
                from n 
                in names    
                select new EntityCollection
                {
                    entityName = n.Name,
                    tags = (
                        from t in model.Entities
                        join to in model.EntityOutlines on t.Outline equals to
                        where t.EntityType.Name.Equals(n.Name)
                        orderby to.EntityData
                        select new EntityMeta
                        {
                            entityData = to.CData,
                            objectId = to.ObjectId,
                            completed = t.Completed,
                            modified = (DateTime) to.Modified, // no idea why I need to cast this
                            comment = t.EntityType.Comment
                        }
                    ).Distinct().ToList(),
                };

            _entityCollection.AddRange(collection);

        }
    }
```

My question is how to acheive this using MVVM? I've seen examples of master and sub viewmodels, where a page might be swapped or where a control in a view is changed dynamically. In my case the view is not changing - same page, same control - but I'm changing considerably the data that I'll be displaying.

My current thinking is that I have a separate private query method in the view model class for each variation of the data I'm sending back and that I switch within the main view model method to decide what data to return.

I'm pretty sure that this will work, but is this the MVVM way?

**Edit:** for clarity.

The final object will be the same. A grouping of my entities in the structure as indicated in my code. However the core entities have relationships to other business objects not currently included in that view (this query just shows everything) so I need to switch what query I run to - say - show this entity structure grouped by relationship A, or B or C. In each case the LINQ query will be very different, chaining further up the (database) entity relationship hierarchy.

So given that the resulting linq query will be wildly different in each case, is having a separate method for each query and then switching this within my view model method a legal way of doing things in MVVM?

**Further edit:** with code.

I'm not fully conversant with MVVM parlance yet, so maybe this pseudo code will help illustrate what I'm thinking of doing. Does this seem sensible?

```
class EntityViewModel {

    public EntityViewModel()
    {
        switch (someEvent)
        {
            case 1:
                buildAllEntityCollection();
            break;

            case 2:
                buildEntitiesGroupedByADifferentObjectA();
            break;

            case 3:
                buildEntitiesGroupedByDifferentObjectsBAndC();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void buildAllEntityCollection()
    {
        // the LINQ query already posted, adds the results of a 
                    //linq query to a list of EntityCollections
        // that is bound to the view
        var collection = some.Linq.query.Tolist();
         _entityCollection.AddRange(collection);
    }

    private void buildEntitiesGroupedByADifferentObjectA()
    {
        // a completely different LINQ query populating 
                    // the same list, binding to the same view
        var collection = some.Linq.query.Tolist();
         _entityCollection.AddRange(collection);
    }

    private void buildEntitiesGroupedByDifferentObjectsBAndC()
    {
        // a completely different LINQ query populating 
                    // the same list, binding to the same view
        var collection = some.Linq.query.Tolist();
         _entityCollection.AddRange(collection);
    }

    List<EntityCollection> EntityCollection
    {
         get { return _entityCollection; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is different between the object types? Property names, property types, hierarchy? You might end up writing a very flexible View (similar to a grid control) that could cost you more time than just creating multiple Views.

Comment: I've updated the question to provide some clarity

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am able to understand the data structure from your explanation you might:

- Design a View (fitting the requirements of the end-user)
- Design a ViewModel that accommodates the View
- Provide a method for each linq query on your repository/data access classes that queries the correct data structures and returns an instance of the ViewModel

The ViewModel in MVVM is responsible for bridging the gap between the View and ViewModel. If the resulting Views and ViewModels are the same there is hardly any reason to make multiple version (unless new insights prompt you to do so)

The bridging is done by calling methods/accessing properties on the Model and by providing properties and commands that can be used by Views. This way the ViewModel only knows about the Model and allows Views to access data and operations.

The ViewModel not knowing the View means that the ViewModel has no dependencies on the View. In its turn the View will be dependent on the ViewModel because it will point to the ViewModel's properties and commands.

Comment: Hi, I've added some pseudo code to illustrate my point, is this the right way of doing it? I guess my confusion is over where to put view model code. ThisEntity.GetEntityByName() clearly lives in the model class for that entity but I'm wondering where to put methods that pull together a lot of entities into my custom object. I thought that this is what the view model was for?

Comment: Correct, the logic that turns the Model into a ViewModel should be in the ViewModel or in between Moel and ViewModel. The Model should NOT know about the ViewModel. In general I add a layer of repositories that contain (Linq)queries in between.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd please explain this: "The ViewModel in MVVM is responsible for bridging the gap between the View and ViewModel."... How can the ViewModel be both at one side of the gap... and at the same time be the bridge between itself and the View? Second problem, more serious: in the MVVM pattern the ViewModel knows nothing about the View... so how can it stand in between? The ViewModel is independent from any View. It is the VIEW that binds itself to the ViewModel. Also your sentence "Design a ViewModel that accomodates the View" is incorrect, for the reason told above.

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus - I added to my answer. I guess you are misunderstanding what I mean by "not knowing". To me this means that the ViewModel does not have any dependencies on the View (it can be compiled, instantiated and tested without the need for a View)